# Scheduling of I/O-bound operations in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

If I'm on a thread which doesn't need to be responsive, and for which continued execution relies on the result of an I/O bound call (HttpClient request), is there any value in implementing the call asynchronously in .NET?

Will Windows know that I'm waiting on an I/O operation and refrain from scheduling the thread until data arrives?

I recall reading somewhere that it does, but I'm afraid I still have difficulty understanding how this works and when I can rely on it.

Comment: Note: I'm thinking possible downsides might be things like having to check aggregate exceptions, task overhead, etc.

Comment: I've selected an answer but I'm still interested to know if anybody can explain a bit about how the OS and CLI work together to avoid scheduling threads waiting on I/O, and will upvote a comment that can positively confirm it with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no value in using async there. As you suspect, Windows will know that the thread is waiting for IO and won't schedule the thread until the data arrives.

However, the idea of async is that you don't really need to create a new thread. The idea of async is that (I'm cutting a few corners here; there is better documentation available on the Internet) it tries to do something like you're doing here manually. So instead of you having to create a new thread, async does this for you. (It doesn't actually create a new thread, but you get the idea.)

If this needs to be high performance, I would not advise to do it the way you're implementing it now. Async would be much better for this. In your case, when you're doing 1000 requests, you would have 1000 threads, which is not a good idea. Async would accomplish this a lot smarter, and will give you better performance.

The basic advantage of using async (besides performance) is that it's like you're actually programming only on the UI thread. Previously, that would have locked up your application, but with async your application stays responsive. That's really the primary advantage of async.

Comment: In this case, I'm not winding up the thread manually, it's coming from either IIS or the framework we're using on top of IIS. So I think this will not be of concern.

Comment: Than you're probably fine. Besides, async probably wouldn't even work (at least not how you expect) because it's meant more for Windows/WPF/Metro applications.